# How can I calculate this limit with the given graph?

Tags: calculus

[[image]]

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f\big(f(x)\big)$$

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxKe7.jpg).)

I don't need an answer, I just want to know how I can calculate the limit based on the given information.

Comment: First determine $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$. Can you do that?

Comment: Oh right, I should I have shown what I know so far. That limit as x approaches 0 of f(x) is = to 2. I understand that. $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 2$$

Comment: Okay, so as $x\to 0$, the argument of the outer $f$ is approaching $2$. Thus, you want $\lim\limits_{x\to ?}f(x)$?

Comment: Is it $$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$$?

Comment: Almost. You have to be a little careful here: no matter how $x\to 0$, $f(x)$ is approaching $2$ from below, so it’s actually the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 2^-$. And as you can see from the graph, it *does* matter.

Comment: Right, I see that now. So if the graph was approaching 0 from above, then we would be finding $$x \to 2^{+}$$. But what happens if the graph is approaching from neither above or below. Say for example I wanted to know $$\lim_{x \to -4} f(f(x))$$?

Comment: That would be easy: when $x$ is near $-4$, the function is constantly $2$, so $f\big(f(x)\big)=f(2)=-1$ in an open interval around $x=-4$. Thus, the limit would be $-1$. (However, that was a good question to ask.)

Comment: Could you possibly explain why that is the case?

Comment: When $x$ is near $-4$, $f(x)$ is always $2$, so $f\big(f(x)\big)$ is always $f(2)$, which is $-1$. The function $f\circ f$ ($f$ composed with $f$) is constant in a neighborhood of $x=-4$, so its limit is its constant value there.

Comment: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I want to disagree with Stefan. You got it right that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$  is 2, but notice that it approaches 2 from the negative direction, going from below 2 towards 2. Therefore you need to calculate $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ as it approaches 2 from the negative direction, which is -2.

Answer (score 0):

The limit at a point exists in general if the right hand and left hand limit at that point equal the actual value of the function at that point. For example at $x=2$, we see that the function maps to $-1$. So if the left hand and right hand limit as $x$ approaches $x=2$ both equal $-1$, then the function is continuous at $x=2$ and the limit exists in general. From the left, the function approaches $-2$ as $x$ approaches $x=2$. From the right the function approaches $2$ as $x$ approaches $x=2$. Therefore since the left hand and right hand limits are not equal to the function value at the point $x=2$ the limit does not exist and the function is discontinuous at $x=2$.

I meant above to be a general case for limits not a direct answer to the question. For composite functions we check the limit of the inside function as $x$ approaches a given value. If this limit exists and equals $L$, all we need to do is check the limit of the outside function as it approaches $L$. We check this limit from the left if the inside function strictly approaches $L$ from underneath, and we check from the right if the inside function approaches $L$ from above. We check the right hand and left hand limit if the inside function approaches $L$ from above and below.

Comment: That includes *continuity*, that is that the limit equals the value of the function.